# jQuery selector question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, fade

I'm working with an jQuery script that has gotten me pretty far but I kind of hit a mountain I can't seem to fix.

On this jsFiddle I simulated the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/nRD4L/2/

So this is the script I'm using, it enables me to click on a span and give it an function which is fine. The problem is a bit with the selector because the way it works now is that it selects the next div after the span to perform that function but due to some styling I can't have that div next to the span, it has to be a few elements before it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.social_media_updates_extended_view').hide();

jQuery(".wrapper_update_extend span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.social_media_updates_extended_view').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(200);
    $this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);
    });

});
```

I made an example on jsFiddle : On this jsFiddle I simulated the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/nRD4L/2/ here you should be able to see the problem. There are 4 span elements that are clickable but only the bottom two work because the div is next to the span but I need to find a way to make the top two div's to work the same like the bottom ones.

Comment: (simulate to accept an answer too) Peter, is it so hard to accept an answer? Give it a try... it's easy. People will like you and you'll get more correct answers from good members. Cheers!

Comment: It actually is, when I click on the +1 I get an box saying "Please login or register to vote for this post" but I'm allready logged in!

Comment: Actually you are still an UNREGISTERED USER. Than register if you like SOverflow. (P.S. I have the right answer for you. I'll post it soon)

Comment: How silly of me, I thought I allready did that, but now I'm registered and gave out some "correct answers" in older topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [working DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/FC2Me/)

code used:

```
$('.social_media_updates_extended_view').hide();
$('.btnFadeIn').css('cursor', 'pointer');

$(".btnFadeIn").click(function() {    
    var $this = $(this);    
    if ( $this.hasClass('active')){return;}

    $('.social_media_updates_extended_view').fadeTo(300, 0);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active').parents('.wrapper_update').find('.social_media_updates_extended_view').fadeTo(300, 1);    
});
```

Comment: Hey Roxon, I wondered if you could assist me a bit more. I allmost have it fixed but I have an problem with my div layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/nRD4L/11/ in this Fiddle you can see I have 3 working span elements but the lowest one does not work due to a small change in the div structure. Any thoughts?

Comment: With the code above it works. Why you have not tried it?! Here: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/nRD4L/62/

Answer (score 1):

add this `$this.parent(".wrapper_update_extend").siblings(".social_media_updates_extended_view").fadeToggle(200);`

under `$this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);`

The above will select the parent `.wrapper_update_extend` and then the sibling `.social_media_updates_extended_view`

Check more for [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) & [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nRD4L/4/

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and it seems to almost work, the problem that remains is that when you click on a span to show the div and then click on the same span again it does not hide the div, it does an toggle (which is logic).

Comment: Man, this brings me back to the days of Action Scripting, God I hated that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the next div in the dom, you can select an element by its *id* attribute using the # selector (like in CSS).

So if you give an id to the html element you want to fadeToggle() for example a DIV element:

```
<div id='myDiv'>The div's content</div>;
```

Then you can fadeToggle() with:

```
$('#myDiv').fadeToggle(200);
```

Assuming you can set element's ids through server side processing, you can consider define ids in couples.

You can see it work at http://jsfiddle.net/nRD4L/14/.

Comment: Yea that would be an pretty easy solution but the content is dynamic so there could be a 100 div's that are hidden and need to be shown so that would mean I need to put those classes inside the script to hide and show making it very large.

Comment: I suppose you generate your dynamic content server side, so you can generate ids for spans and div such as span-1/div-1, span-2/div-2 etc.. Then you may apply fadeToggle to $('#div-' + $this.id.substring($this.id.indexOf('-') + 1)). So you can manage objects independently from thier position in the DOM.